# Conditional distribution distributed as notation

Tags: probability, notation

What's the proper way to write:

$$(X \mid \mu = t) \sim \mathcal{N} (t, 1)$$

Some people write it as $X|\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, 1)$, however I find this confusing as it isn't clear what is a random variable and what is a constant here.

Comment: What is $\mu$? The expected value? Is $\mu$ a random variable or a constant?

Comment: @Bernhard $\mu$ is a random variable, $t$ is a value it can take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define an upper case $M$ to be the random expected value and then write

$$ (X|M=\mu)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,1) $$

or

$$ X|_M \sim \mathcal{N}(M,1) $$

It is essentially the same that you wrote, only that the convention of using upper case letters for random variables helps.

Comment: Ok I'll stick to the first one if it's a reasonable notation but I still find the second rather confusing.

Comment: I agree. If the parentheses are unwieldy then how about: $X|_{M=\mu}$

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's pretty simple, you can define $Y \sim \mathcal{N} (0, 1)$ and then:

$$ X = \mu + Y$$

or

$$ X = \mu + \mathcal{N} (0, 1)$$

Comment: Why not? $(X| \mu = t) \sim \mathcal{N}(t,1)$

Comment: Well I can see that in your definition $(X|\mu =t) \sim \mathcal{N}(t, 1)$ $P_\mu$ a.s. through substitution, but how do you see the converse, i.e. my definition implies that $X$ is equal to yours a.s. in some sense?

Comment: This entire "regular conditional probability" is very confusing for me as well. Actually, I'm not even certain what is the meaning of "almost surely" here, since I don't really understand what is the probability space. The real question is what does it mean $(X| \mu = t)$? It's a random variable, but what is the probability space? If $P(\mu=t)=0$ for every $t$,  how do you define it?

Comment: I think the point of regular conditional probability is that $P(\mu=t) = 0$ means it can't be defined as division, only as a set of properties.